# Reproducing Josef Albers factory series (repeating rectangle patterns)

Tags: graphics, generative-art, polygons

Josef Albers (1888 - 1976) was a German-born American artist. In
1920, Albers joined the Weimar Bauhaus as a student and became a
faculty member in 1922, teaching the principles of handicrafts.

[image]

*Josef Albers, Aufwärts (Upwards), ca. 1926*

With the Bauhaus's move to Dessau in 1925, he was promoted to professor and married Anni Albers, a student at the institution who was to become famous as a textile artist:

[How to weave Anni Albers Red Meander carpet?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292906/how-to-weave-anni-albers-red-meander-carpet)

Following the Bauhaus's closure under Nazi pressure in 1933, Josef and Anni Albers emigrated to the United States. He was appointed as the
head of the painting program at  Black Mountain College in North
Carolina, a position he held until 1949.

[image]

Josef Albers (left) with Buckminster Fuller (Mid) and students at
Black Mountain College, summer 1948: [Construction of a geodesic dome.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292697/construction-of-a-fuller-dome)

In 1950, Albers left Black Mountain to head the department of design
at Yale University. He is considered to be one of the most
influential teachers of visual art in the twentieth century.

Between 1925 and 1929 Albers produced a series of abstract paintings,
which I would like to replicate with Mathematica. Here is another one of
them:

[image]

*Josef Albers, Fabrik (Factory), 1925*

More pieces of the series can be seen at the [Josef & Anni Albers Foundation](https://www.albersfoundation.org/art/highlights/fabrik-factory)

**My request**

Can we produce rectangular patterns like these with a certain amount
of randomness?

Comment: Albers like Mondrian had a deep interest in perception and the interaction of color.   See earlier thread [Composition-à-la-Mondrian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59620/composition-à-la-mondrian/59634#59634) and his wonderful book on the subject: [The Interaction of Color](https://yalebooks.yale.edu/book/9780300179354/interaction-of-color/)

Comment: Thank you, Jagra, nice observation. I asked a Mondrian - question some years ago: [Composition à la Mondrian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59620/composition-%c3%a0-la-mondrian), and I just realized that there is a [RandomMondrian](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomMondrian/) in the Repository

Comment: Ha!  I hadn't remembered that you asked the earlier question.  Nice to see that you have retained your interest in all of this.  Keen to see what you develop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- We use `KroneckerProduct` to create some `{0,1}`-matrixs.
- `{m1,m2,...,m6,m7}` are several types of such `{0,1}`-matrixs.
- We set random grid points in the rectangle and choose some type of such matrixs and use `Plus` to mixing the types.

```
k = 8;
m1 = KroneckerProduct[PadRight[{0, 1}, k, "Periodic"], 
   PadRight[{0, 1}, k, "Periodic"]];
m2 = KroneckerProduct[PadRight[{0, 1}, k, "Periodic"], 
   PadRight[{1, 0}, k, "Periodic"]];
m3 = KroneckerProduct[PadRight[{1, 0}, k, "Periodic"], 
   PadRight[{0, 1}, k, "Periodic"]];
m4 = KroneckerProduct[PadRight[{1, 0}, k, "Periodic"], 
   PadRight[{1, 0}, k, "Periodic"]];
m5 = KroneckerProduct[PadRight[{1, 1}, k, "Periodic"], 
   PadRight[{1, 0}, k, "Periodic"]];
m6 = KroneckerProduct[PadRight[{1, 0}, k, "Periodic"], 
   PadRight[{1, 1}, k, "Periodic"]];
m7 = KroneckerProduct[PadRight[{1, 1}, k, "Periodic"], 
   PadRight[{1, 1}, k, "Periodic"]];
ArrayPlot/@{m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7}
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 25;
ArrayPlot[
 SparseArray[
  MapThread[
   Rule[Band[#1], #2] &, {RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, 2}], 
    Table[RandomChoice[{m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7}] + 
      RandomChoice[{m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6}], n]}]], 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> Black, 2 -> White}]
```

[image]

- For the first picture, we can maily use type `m6` and `m7` by setting `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}->{m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7}`.

```
Clear[m, n];
SeedRandom[1];
m = 5  k;
n = 3  k; 
c = .9; 
pts = 
 RandomSample[Tuples[{Range[m], Range[n]}], Floor[m*n*c]]; ArrayPlot[
 SparseArray[
  MapThread[
   Rule[Band[#1], #2] &, {pts, 
    Table[RandomChoice[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1} -> {m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, 
         m6, m7}] + 
      RandomChoice[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1} -> {m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, 
         m7}], Length@pts]}]], 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Black, 2 -> Lighter@Blue}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Clearly, there is room for automation here.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

rules = {1 -> Black, 2 -> Lighter@Blue, 3 -> White, 4 -> White, 
   5 -> Lighter@Blue, 6 -> Black};
parts = IntegerPartitions[30, {1, 6}] // Select[4 < Length@# < 8 &];
runs = RandomSample[parts, 40] // 
   Map[RotateLeft[#, RandomInteger[{1, 3}]] &];
cols = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, Length@#] & /@ runs;
cbars = (MapThread[Thread[{#1, #2}] &, {runs, cols}] /. {a_, b_} :> 
     Sequence @@ ConstantArray[Lookup[rules, b], a]);
```

To check where the errors (if any) can come from:

```
Dimensions /@ {rules, parts, runs, cols, cbars}

ArrayPlot[{
     cbars[[1]], cbars[[2]]
     , cbars[[1]], cbars[[2]]
     , cbars[[1]], cbars[[2]]
     
     , cbars[[9]], cbars[[6]]
     , cbars[[9]], cbars[[6]]
     , cbars[[9]], cbars[[6]]
     , cbars[[9]], cbars[[6]]
     
     , cbars[[21]], cbars[[15]]
     , cbars[[21]], cbars[[15]]
     , cbars[[21]], cbars[[15]]
     , cbars[[21]], cbars[[15]]
     
     , cbars[[10]], cbars[[13]]
     , cbars[[10]], cbars[[13]]
     , cbars[[10]], cbars[[13]]
     , cbars[[10]], cbars[[13]]
     
     , cbars[[22]], cbars[[25]]
     , cbars[[22]], cbars[[25]]
     , cbars[[22]], cbars[[25]]
     , cbars[[2]], cbars[[25]]
     , cbars[[2]], cbars[[25]]
     } // 
    SubsetMap[
      RotateLeft[#, RandomInteger[{3, 6}]] &, #, {All, 
       RandomInteger[{8, 12}]}] & //
   SubsetMap[
     RotateLeft[#, RandomInteger[{3, 6}]] &, #, {All, 
      RandomInteger[{18, 22}]}] & //
  SubsetMap[
    RotateLeft[#, RandomInteger[{3, 6}]] &, #, {All, 
     RandomInteger[{28, 30}]}] &
 ]
```

---

A typical output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[albersFabrik]

albersFabrik[clrs_ : Automatic, lines_ : Automatic, d_ : Automatic, 
   t_ : 15][opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{c = clrs /. Automatic -> {Black, Red, White}, 
   n = d /. Automatic -> 10}, 
  Graphics[
   Map[{Last[c = RotateRight[c]], 
       CapForm["Square"], AbsoluteThickness[t], Line @ #} &]@
    RandomSample @
     Map[Table[
         RandomChoice[{Map[Reverse], Identity}]@RandomSample[#, 2], 
         lines /. Automatic -> 20] &]@
      Outer[List, Range[0, 3  n, 3], Range[0, 3 n, 3]], opts, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, 
   Background -> First[clrs /. Automatic -> {Black, Red, White}], 
   PlotRangePadding -> 2]]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[777];

Row[{albersFabrik[][], albersFabrik[][], albersFabrik[][]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{albersFabrik[RandomColor[3]][], 
     albersFabrik[RandomColor[3]][], 
     albersFabrik[RandomColor[3]][]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{albersFabrik[Automatic, 4][], 
     albersFabrik[Automatic, 15][], 
     albersFabrik[Automatic, 25][]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
upwards := Module[
  {colors = {Lighter@Blue, Black, White}, partitions = 8, rows = 40, cols = 30, matrix, part},
  {part["rows"], part["cols"]} = 
     Partition[Join[{1}, Sort@RandomSample[Range[2, # - 1], partitions], {#}], 2, 1] & 
       /@ {rows, cols};
  matrix = Array[If[ Mod[#, 2] == 0, Lighter@Blue, Black] &, {rows, cols}] ;
  Outer[{rows, cols} |->
    matrix[[Span @@ rows, Span @@ cols]] //= 
      ReplaceAll[#,  Rule @@ RandomSample[colors, 2]] &, part["rows"], part["cols"], 1];
  matrix // ArrayPlot]

SeedRandom[1];
Multicolumn[Table[upwards, 6], 3]
```

[image]